# How to solve $2n^2 - 3n + 1 \equiv{0} \pmod{250}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am doing homework for one of my classes and I got stuck at this:
$2n^2 - 3n + 1 \equiv{0} \pmod{250}$

Wolfram alpha show solutions $1 + 250c$ and $63 + 250c$, where c is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the equation in $2n^2 - 3n + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and $2n^2 - 3n + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {5^3}$

From the first equation we can see that $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, while the second can be solved using the [Hensel's Lifting Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) and then glue the two results using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: Thanks, I used the mentioned methods and got the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

First factor $2n^2-3n+1$ into $(2n-1)(n-1)$ and $250$ into $2\cdot5^3$. Now notice that $2n-1$ and $n-1$ can only share a factor if their difference, i.e. $n$, also has a common factor (but $n$ is coprime to $n-1$ and thus also to $2n-1$). So either $1\mid n-1$ and $250\mid2n-1$, $1\mid 2n-1$ and $250\mid n-1$, $2\mid n-1$ and $5^3\mid2n-1$, or $2\mid2n-1$ and $5^3\mid n-1$. The first and last cases are impossible because $2$ cannot divide an odd number, and the second case is solved by $n=1+250k$. Now to solve the third case denote $2n=1+5^3m$. Since $2n-1$ is odd, $m$ has to be an odd number...but after plugging in $m=2m'-1$ you get $2n=250m'-124$ , or $n=125m'-62$, and in order for $n$ to be odd $m'$ must be odd as well; thus $n=125(2c+1)-62=250c+63$.

Comment: The first sentence is worth +1 by itself.  Factoring is *extremely* useful in problems like this.